# Efficient alternative to for loop over grouped data to calculate conditional rolling max and min

Tags: r, performance, data.table, query-performance

I am using the following for loop in my code to obtain the lowest upper margin and highest lower margin of values in my data table.

My data looks like this:

```
g1  g2  v1   RRP  AVAILABLE  FORSALE  ACCEPT  REJECT  
 A   1  -29   55          1        1       0       0 
 A   1  -28   45          1        0       0       1  
 A   1  -27   51          1        0       0       1 
 A   1  -26   50          1        1       1       0  
 A   1  -25   48          1        0       0       0 
 A   1  -24   37          1        1       1       0 
 A   1  -23   39          1        1       0       0  
 A   1  -22   35          1        0       0       1  
 A   1  -21   32          1        0       0       0  
 A   1  -20   45          1        1       0       0  
 A   1  -19   50          1        1       1       0 
 A   1  -18   44          0        1       0       0
```

This is the for loop I am using. I am unsure how to improve the performance of this code, because I cannot think of a better way to deal with the rolling values for **HLM** and **LUM** which are needed to calculate the values of the next **HLM** and **LUM** in the table, for each group.  In regards to the number **31** in the setup for my **for loops**, there are precisely **31** rows of data in each group.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(d1)/31){
    HLM <- -1000
    LUM <- 10000
    for(j in 1:31){
        x <- x+1
        if(d1$AVAILABLE[x]){
            d1$HLM[x] <- ifelse(!d1$ACCEPT[x]&!d1$FORSALE[x],max(d1$RRP[x],HLM),
                          min(d1$RRP[x],HLM))
            HLM <- d1$HLM[x]
            d1$LUM[x] <- ifelse(!d1$REJECT[x]&d1$FORSALE[x],min(d1$RRP[x],LUM),
                          max(d1$RRP[x],LUM))
            LUM <- d1$LUM[x]
        if(LUM < HLM & d1$ACCEPT[x]){
            d1$HLM[x] <- d1$LUM[x]
            HLM <- LUM
        }
        if(LUM < HLM & d1$REJECT[x]){
            d1$LUM[x] <- d1$HLM[x]
            LUM <- HLM
        }
    }
    if(!d1$AVAILABLE[x]){
        d1$HLM[x] <- -1000
        d1$LUM[x] <- 10000
}
```

The returned values look like this:

```
g1  g2  v1   RRP  AVAILABLE  FORSALE  ACCEPT  REJECT  cMax  cMin
 A   1  -29   55          1        1       0       0    50 -1000  
 A   1  -28   45          1        0       0       1    50    45  
 A   1  -27   51          1        0       0       1    51    51
 A   1  -26   50          1        1       1       0    50    50
 A   1  -25   48          1        0       0       0    50    48
 A   1  -24   37          1        1       1       0    37    37
 A   1  -23   39          1        1       0       0    39    37
 A   1  -22   35          1        0       0       1    39    35 
 A   1  -21   32          1        0       0       0    36    35
 A   1  -20   45          1        1       0       0    45    35
 A   1  -19   50          1        1       1       0    45    35   
 A   1  -18   44          0        1       0       0    44    35
```

The logic of my code is this:

- **g1,g2** are grouping variables
- **v1** determines the order of rows in each group (ascending)
- **RRP** is the value of interest
- **AVAILABLE** is a conditional variable. If false, set **HLM** and **LUM** to defaults
- **FORSALE** is a conditional variable used for calculating HLM and LUM when AVAILABLE is true.
- **ACCEPT** is a conditional variable that can increase the value of the lowest upper margin, which may require the **HLM** to be adjusted in response so that is never greater than the **LUM**
- **REJECT** is a conditional variable that has a similar effect to **ACCEPT**, except in terms of the **HLM** overwriting the **LUM** instead.

Comment: Can you use dput function to paste the data? There is no way to verify a solution.

Comment: Sorry but this is tldr

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R calculating upper and lower marginal values for each group in a data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54797644/r-calculating-upper-and-lower-marginal-values-for-each-group-in-a-data-table)